# In profinite group $G$ with inverse system $(G_\alpha)%$, how the kernel of projection map becomes the basis of neighborhood for $1$ in $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, fundamental-groups, galois-extensions, profinite-groups

In profinite group $G$ with inverse system $(G_\alpha,\phi_{\alpha,\beta} )%$, how the kernel of projection map $G\rightarrow G_\alpha$becomes the basis of neighborhood for $1$ in $G$?

I couldn't understand this sentence in p.21 of the book 'Galois groups and Fundamental groups, Tamas Szamuely'.

[image]

Comment: Notice that the topology of a profinite group is induced by the product topology and recall what's the definition of product topology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the construction of the topology on a profinite group (the projective limit $P$ of a directed set of finite groups $G_\alpha$): all the groups $G_\alpha$ are given the discrete topology, so that in particular $\{1_{G_\alpha}\}$ is open. The projective limit then has the subspace topology inside $\prod_\alpha G_\alpha$.

Let us set some definitions straight:

- An open set in the product topology of $\prod_\alpha G_\alpha$ is of the form $\prod_\alpha U_\alpha$, where $U_\alpha\subset G_\alpha$ is open and $U_\alpha=G_\alpha$ for all but finitely many $\alpha$. In other words, it is a finite intersection of sets of the form $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ for $U_\alpha\subset G_\alpha$ open.
- A neighbourhood basis for $1$ in the projective limit $P$ is a set of open neighbourhoods $\mathscr{N}$ such that for any open subset $U\subset P$ that contains $1$, there exists $ N\in \mathscr{N}$ that is contained in $U$.

Can you now see that the open sets $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(\{1_{G_\alpha}\})=\operatorname{Ker} \pi_\alpha$  form a neighbourhood basis for $1$ in the profinite group?